# Change poisition of responsive view in chrome's devtools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This is how responsive view looks like in the newest chrome version. But I would like to have this view on the left side, like in older versions, so I can mouse-over element in the devtools and see them revealing in the view. Since that view is in the middle of window, then I can't have devtools opened in the bigger sizes.

[image]

Comment: You can't change the position of the view as it is meant to line up with the bars, probably for convenience of selecting different sizes. You could just undock your DevTools window instead.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see now. Ok, thanks for info.